# How to set focus on input on load and remove focus when browser auto populate saved credentials

Tags: javascript, html, angular

I have a simple login page in angular6, I want to set focus to the input field when the login page is loaded and remove focus if the browser auto-populate saved credentials.

I am setting focus on ngOnInit() using simple javascript `document.getElementById("userName").focus();`
This sets focus to input(username) field when login page loads but I want to remove focus if browser auto populate saved details.
I tried to capture the values using (change) event but it doesnt work.

Please guide on this

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

Very few browsers actually trigger the input change event on autofill. If the change event doesn't work, try binding your input to a model:

```js
export class MyComponent {
  login: string;
  @ViewChild('loginInput') loginInput: ElementRef;
  
  ngOnInit() {
    this.loginInput.nativeElement.focus();
  }
  
  blurInput() {
    this.loginInput.nativeElement.blur();
  }
}
```

```html
<input type="text" [ngModel]="login" (ngModelChange)="blurInput()" [ngModelOptions]="{ standalone: true }" #loginInput>
```